# Выборка полей из массива mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Есть записи вида:

```
{
    "_id" : "9a4b7791-c0ff-11e5-84d2-0cc47a13d3da",
    "dateEdit" : "2019-07-08 14:39:38",
    "categoriesID" : {
        "categoryId" : [ 
            {
                "text" : "db710657-ba27-4245-9c12-5ab37f50a962"
            }
        ]
    },
    "model" : "Glossa Коробка накладного монтажа, перламутр",
    "producer" : "Schneider Electric",
    "vendorCode" : "GSL000600",
    "series" : "GLOSSA",
    "discountCode" : "b530121c-5b1d-11e3-8764-00259096c80e",
    "mainImage" : "https://www.tesli.com/upload/iblock/42a/9a4b7791_c0ff_11e5_84d2_0cc47a13d3da.jpg",
    "images" : {
        "image" : []
    },
    "stepCount" : "1",
    "params" : {
        "param" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "Тип товара",
                "id" : "16b8f0b6-d400-4c5c-b73a-a8c058ddb0bd",
                "value" : "Коробка открытого монтажа 1-местная"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Производитель",
                "id" : "3846d1fd-f013-426f-9ba3-e9a662844c01",
                "value" : "Schneider Electric"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Артикул",
                "id" : "bitrix-q7sgmzei-4rcp-mt1a-jqig-jfwpei6v4u5j",
                "value" : "SCGSL000600"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Необходимо вытащить "_id" и те элементы массива param, у которого name == Артикул
Пробовал сделать так:

```
db.getCollection('Offers').find({ }, { "_id" : "1", 
    $where: function() { 
       return this.params.param.length==3 && this.params.param.every(function(el){
           return el.name=="Артикул";
       });
    }} )
```

_id вытаскивает, а значения из массива param нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помимо этого пробовал следующим образом :

```
db.getCollection('Offers').find({ }, { "_id" : "1", 
    "params.param" :  {"name" : "Артикул"}} )
```

Выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот так:

```
db.getCollection('Offers').find({ }, { "_id" : "1", 
    "params.param.name" :  "Артикул"} )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно получить элементы массива param со значением name = Артикул?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('Offers').aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "params.param": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$params.param",
          as: "param",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$param.name",
              "Артикул"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```